# How can I use Zend\Di in Zend\ServiceManager in ZF2?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I'm trying to make the Zend\ServiceManager use Zend\Di to create my instances, since I have pre-scanned and cached DI definitions already. I realize this might come with a speed penalty but on the other hand, I need to write a lot less meta-code.

The [ServiceManager documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html) says that

> the ServiceManager also provides optional ties to Zend\Di, allowing Di
>   to act as an initializer or an abstract factory for the manager.

But I don't find any examples of how make the ServiceManager use Zend\Di. I'm not even sure where I should set this up, maybe in Module::getServiceConfig()? Can anyone provide some example code?

Comment: i haven't used DI almost since the SM was introduced, but iirc there were abstract factory for servicemanager, which accepted DI instance and then acted as ServiceManager to Di proxy. Look for factories under https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/Di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. In order to make Zend\Di compatible with Zend\ServiceManager, I extended a class MyLib\Di\Di from Zend\Di\Di which implements the AbstractFactoryInterface.

```
namespace MyLib\Di;
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface; 
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Di extends \Zend\Di\Di implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return $this->get($requestedName);
    }
}
```

Now, I can use MyLib\Di\Di as a fallback abstract factory for Zend\ServiceManager. Here's an example of how I create my IndexController. The IndexController's dependencies (constructor parameters) are injected automatically.

```
class Module
{
    ... 

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {        
        $this->di = new \MyLib\Di\Di;
        $this->configureDi($this->di); // Set up definitions and shared instances

        return array(
            'abstract_factories' => array($this->di),
        );
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Survey\Controller\IndexController' => function() {
                    return $this->di->get('Survey\Controller\IndexController');
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option - add to config/module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Service\User'              => 'Application\Service\User',
    ),
  ),
```

then class needs to implement Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface

When initiated, serviceManager instance is going to be injected, then you can use something like this in class:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
```

second option would be to put it into Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
```

Comment: that is not the answer how to use `Zend\Di` with `Zend\ServiceManager`

Comment: well, what you are describing is deprecated way used in ZF2 beta versions

Comment: Di? nope, it is not deprecated. It is not recommended unless you know what are you doing.

Comment: as i told, i haven't used it since beta. that is why it was in comment and not as answer. I will ask ocramius how he uses it.